# Is there a way of defining what collection to use when using passport.authenticate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

Within my project I have both hcpuser and regular user. I have got the registration working for HCP but when i go to do my login function it still only reads from my users collection and not from the hcpuser I want it to. Is there a simple line of code I can declare before my function that allows this.

Hcp model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var User = require('../model/user.model').schema

var schema = new Schema({
    email : {type:String, require:true},
    username: {type:String, require:true},
    password:{type:String, require:true},
    creation_dt:{type:Date, require:true},
    hcp : {type:Boolean, require : true},
    clinic:{type:String, require:true},
    patients: [User],
});

schema.statics.hashPassword = function hashPassword(password){
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password,10);
}

schema.methods.isValid = function(hashedpassword){
    return  bcrypt.compareSync(hashedpassword, this.password);
}
schema.set('collection', 'hcpuser');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Hcpuser',schema);
```

Hcp controller with first register function working as expected.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");

const router = express.Router();
const Hcpusermodel = mongoose.model("Hcpuser")
const {ObjectId} = require("mongodb");
var Hcpuser = require('../model/hcp.model')
var passport = require('passport');

router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
    addToDB(req, res);
  });


  async function addToDB(req, res) {

    var hcpuser = new Hcpuser({
      email: req.body.email,
      hcp : true,
      username: req.body.username,
      password: Hcpuser.hashPassword(req.body.password),
      clinic: req.body.clinic,
      creation_dt: Date.now()

    });

    try {
      doc = await hcpuser.save();
      return res.status(201).json(doc);
    }
    catch (err) {
      return res.status(501).json(err);
    }
  }

  //login
  router.post('/login', function(req,res,next){

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, hcpuser, info) {
      if (err) { return res.status(501).json(err); }
      if (!hcpuser) { return res.status(501).json(info); }
      req.logIn(hcpuser, function(err) {
        if (err) { return res.status(501).json(err); }
        return res.status(200).json({message:'Login Success'});
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, you either want to auth one OR the other, or check both - I think you're asking for how to auth separately (one OR the other, not both)?

*please note, this specific code has been untested, but the principles are there and still stand.*

### One OR the Other

You need to define the name of each strategy in your passport code.

For example:

```
passport.use('users', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'user[email]',
  passwordField: 'user[password]',
},(email, password, done) => {
  Users.findOne({ email })
    .then((user) => {
      if(!user || !user.validatePassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { errors: { 'email or password' : 'is valid' } });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    }).catch(done);
}));


passport.use('hcpusers', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'user[email]',
  passwordField: 'user[password]',
},(email, password, done) => {
  HCPUser.findOne({ email })
    .then((user) => {
      if(!user || !user.validatePassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { errors: { 'email or password' : 'is valid' } });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    }).catch(done);
}));
```

And then in your `passport.authenticate` method, specify the strategy name:

```
passport.authenticate('users', function(err, user, info) { ...
```

and

```
passport.authenticate('hcpusers', function(err, user, info) { ...
```

In this case you'll need two separate endpoints for each login method, or just an extra parameter specifying which one to check from an if statement.

### Update

For your comment of not knowing where the passport code should be, this is up to you. However, I like to keep passport code in an 'auth' folder and add the following code to a passport.js file:

```
const mongose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

const Users = mongose.model('Users');

passport.use('...', new LocalStrategy({
...
...
}));
```

Include this in your server/index/app.js (whatever yours is) `app.use(passport.initialize());`

You can then just use the passport code as normal in your user controllers.

My passport.authenticate code looks like:

```
return passport.authenticate('local', function(err, passUser, info) {
    if (err) { 
      return next(err); 
    }
    if (!passUser) { 
      return res.status(503).send('error'); 
    }
    const user = passUser;
    user.token = user.generateJWT();
    return res.json({ token: user.token });
  })(req, res, next);
```

But this can be different for you (i.e. you may not be using sessions?) Either way, if authenticated, just send the response to client so it can proceed.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for taking the time to reply. Just have a few quick questions, I am trying to do the one or the other. So when I create the local strategy what all do i need to include in my passport.authenticate? do i just need to call the strategy?

Comment: Also i am not quite sure where i should define the local strategy

Comment: Hi @Canices7 - I will update my answer in correspondence to your comment

Comment: Also, if this eventually answers your question, don't forget to accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi so to solve this issue i followed what was mentioned. I needed to define the name of the collection within the hcp model using this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Hcpuser', Hcpuser, 'Hcpuser');
```

I then created a local strategy ensuring that i was searching using the right model which would then point to the right collection within my DB.

Solution:

```
      var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use('hcplocal', new LocalStrategy(
  function(uemail, password, done) {
    Hcpuser.findOne({ "email" : uemail }, function(err, user) { console.log(user)
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        console.log(user);
        console.log(err);

        console.log(uemail)
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email.' });

      }
      if (!user.isValid(password)) {
        console.log(user);
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));


router.post('/login',function(req,res,next){
  passport.authenticate('hcplocal', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return res.status(501).json(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.status(501).json(info); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return res.status(501).json(err); }
      console.log(user);
      return res.status(200).json({message:'Login Success'});

    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```